# Load Balancer for QuickFIXJ Session

Tags: java, apache, quickfixj, camel-quickfix

We have single session with our broker. We are getting market data on that session. Basically we want to distribute that data to different team on FIX only. Is there any ready solution which can work both as acceptor and initaor.

Initator would get message from Broker and would pass those to acceptor and acceptor would pass those messages to it's client.

We are using apache camel quickfixj for this.

Answer (score 0):

Acceptor and initiator are properties of a Fix session, and determine which server on each side of the session creates the FIX connection and which server sits and waits for the other to connect. It's not related to what the server does with the received information.

So your application will receive market data over one FIX session, and you will discuss with your broker as to whether this should be an acceptor or initiator.

Your application can create more FIX sessions with your other team; it is up to you and the other team to decide whether this other session on your side is an acceptor or not.